# Excel VBA find string in column then delete all remaining row in worksheet

Tags: excel, find, row

I am extremely new to VBA coding for excel and i really need to achieve this on 30 more workbooks containing each 250 worksheets...

I need a VBA macro that can :

- find a string which match the entire cell contents and get row number (a)
- find the number of row contain in the worksheet (b)
- then delete all rows from a to b

Can anyone help ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Time to do some research and try some things yourself. Nobody is likely to do your whole project for you. But 250 worksheets? Time for a re-think perhaps.

Comment: I perfectly understand your reaction but i did do some research and not knowing any coding language but understanding it when i read i am unable to create this macro. I tried but I miss the very basics for it. Unfortunately I can not rethink the 250 worksheets per workbook. I don't really have the time (meaning work hours ) to keep on looking for a solution to optimise this. Therefore I will just keep on hoping that a good soul would help me, maybe.

Comment: You've made a useful first step of breaking your project into stages. So start with "find a string". There's tons online on all this stuff. The Find method might be the way to go. If you get stuck on that bit post back with a specific question and your code. That's how this site works. [ask]. If you don't want to get into coding at all you're probably in the wrong place, but there are other VBA sites.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Just in case someone stubble on this post through search and/or google :

I posted it [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/asmmhe/excel_vba_find_string_in_column_then_delete_all/) and a kind soul gave me the answer :

```
Sub DeleteRowsAfterFinding3()

Dim i As Long
Dim rangeFound As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    Set rangeFound = ws.Range("A:A").Find("SOMETHING", Lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not rangeFound Is Nothing Then
        For i = rangeFound.Row + 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            ws.Rows(rangeFound.Row + 1).Delete
        Next i
    End If

Next ws

End Sub
```